# Nginx error log

Tags: 14.04

I have a linux instance on Digital Ocean, and I keep on getting the following nginx error log

`2015/03/06 17:40:48 [error] 2117#0: *116 "/usr/share/nginx/www/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 50.186.40.95, server$`

But my application lives at `/home/nickeleres` and doesnt require an entry point (Meteor, if that matters).

Ive been following this DigitalOcean [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx) but the author makes no reference to changing the following lines in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/nickeleres`

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html; # root is irrelevant
index index.html index.htm; # this is also irrelevant
```

which is where it appears nginx is getting the index.html directive from

This this an error within my nginx config, a coder error, or something else?

Answer (score -1):

Try commenting out the lines marked as irrelevant by placing an # at the beginning of the line.

```
#root /usr/share/nginx/html; # root is irrelevant
#index index.html index.htm; # this is also irrelevant
```

Then reload nginx with:

```
sudo service reload nginx
```

Comment: my `/etc/nginx/sites-available` contains `example` and `nickeleres`

Comment: does that answer your question? excuse my noob status with linux

Comment: is that a real suggestion or are you guessing?

Comment: If you do not require an entry point, then you do not need to define "root" and "index" default document configuration. By leaving them in place without actually satisfying the configuration,nginx tries to resolve them and fails.

Comment: Ive done that, and Im receiving the same error log; do I have to change it in another place?
`2015/03/11 12:46:39 [error] 2114#0: *420 "/usr/share/nginx/www/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 199.223.125.109, server: nickeleres.com, request$`

Comment: Per my original guess, if `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example` is running you may see that sort of behavior. If you don't want that example site to run you can stop it with `rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example` followed by `sudo service nginx reload`